# Custom data in pyro cms pages, such as images or other data

Tags: pyrocms

I'm wondering how in PyroCMS I can add a custom field to a page. Ideally I would like to have an image area at the top of the layout, and have a custom field in pyro that would allow someone to populate that image from the pages module. I realize that there are some image plugins that allow me to attach images to pages, but I would like to be able to add the images directly into the page in the admin (as well as other custom fields for the pages). Even on a separate tab would be fine with me. I'm fine building something if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently if you want to add a custom field to a page you have to hack the module. This is *obviously* not ideal and im not really suggesting it, but I had to do it for http://tedco.org/business to add a "Subtitle" field to each page.

2.2/develop is having its Pages and Blogs moved over to Streams, so you can add custom fields to all pages globally, meaning you can add an image in if you like, or append a US State for some reason, or add a slider. Whipee!

So right now: Hack it or wait. 2.2/develop will have your feature in a week or two.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do this directly from the pages module yet or not without some customization (possible hacking) though, I just asked and will update if possible.

In the meantime this might be helpful:

Consider looking into [PyroStreams.](https://www.pyrocms.com/store/details/pyrostreams) for this though, it will require the Pro version of PyroCMS or you can purchase it from [Parse19](http://parse19.com/pyrostreams/) directly.

You might find [this article](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/concepts/organization) helpful about organization and page layouts.

Here is an article called [Dynamic Pages with PyroCMS and PyroStreams](http://blog.adamfairholm.com/dynamic-pages-with-pyrocms-and-pyrostreams/) though, it's a bit outdated now.

You may also make use of the [gallery module](https://www.pyrocms.com/store/details/galleries), which is free though, I'm not sure this will meet your needs.

Comment: I added something like this into the core of my own fork. You can take a look at github.com/bloveless/pyrocms. I don't know how to get the pyro streams working the way I would like them to, but have heard that there will be the possibility of custom fields in pages as of pyro 2.2

Comment: This will be a great feature for the Pages module come 2.2. Maybe worth waiting for if there is still time and or the project deadline can be adjusted.